# SQL SERVER: How to declare variables and set them with a where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Im kinda new to this so let me try to explain my problem as clear as possible:

**Goal:**
I want to insert a row in datatable1 After an insert in datatable2. so far so good.
But based on certain values in datatable2 I want different values inserted in datatable 1.

**For example:**

If Column1 = 1 and Column2 =1 then I want to insert '123' to Column1 of DT1

If Column1 = 1 and Column2 =0 then I want to insert '123'

If Column1 = 0 and Column2 =1 then I want to insert '456'

Not the best example but it works.

**Code I have so far:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER1

ON Datatable2

AFTER INSERT

AS

Declare @VAR varchar(20)

        @VAR2 varchar (20);


SELECT @VAR = "123";


SELECT @VAR2 = ins.Column999 FROM INSERTED ins;



INSERT INTO datatable1


           (Column1,Column2)

     VALUES

           (@VAR, @VAR2)
```

**Question:**

How do I change up this code with (I assume) a where function so I can insert different values

Comment: Your trigger breaks if multiple rows are inserted together. Remember that the `inserted` and `deleted` tables can contain many rows.

Comment: BTW, there is a difference between `SET @varName = value` instead of `SELECT @varName = value` .

Comment: Your example isn't very fleshed out. E.g. it's not very clear what you're expecting to happen if both columns are `1` or if neither is. Try to come up with a few complete sample rows to insert into `datatable2` and the corresponding rows you'd expect to see in `datatable1` afterwards.

Comment: Triggers are rarely the correct answer to anything. Perhaps you could explain what you are really trying to do

Comment: I suspect there are two concepts and syntaxes that will get you closer to what you're after: First is doing an `INSERT` from a `SELECT` statement, the other is using `CASE` statements in your query

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  thanks for your feedback. I changed the example a bit

Comment: @Jasper Did you try this using Stored Procedure? Trigeers are unreliable and can impact on Performance of the database